# Multiple Data Types in Class Initialization (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, class, types, initialization

EDIT: SOLVED. Multiple data types were not the culprit; the code below works fine. Apparently, I had a mismatch somewhere else.

I am an amateur programmer, and new to Ruby. I am trying to make a class that can be initialized with multiple datatypes. What I mean is this:

I have, say, a "player class". I want to initialize it by setting the name (a string) and the x and y positions (integers in this case). However, I get an error when I do something like this:

```
#Player class containing name:string, x:integer, y:integer
class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :x, :y
  def initialize(name,x,y) #Edit: I forgot to put "def" here in my example. This was not my problem, though.
  @name = name
  @x = x
  @y = y
  end
end

#Create player "Luke" at x:5, y:5
player = Player.new("Luke",5,5)
```

The error seems to be that it is expecting all parameters to be one datatype, such as strings, floats, or integers, etc.

How can I specify different datatypes in my class initialization method?

Comment: Rather than telling us your bizarre interpretation of the error, tell us what the error message actually is.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me in Ruby 1.9.2p180 in Windows.  I even added these lines to inspect the data and they behave as expected:

```
p player.name  # => "Luke"
p player.x     # => 5
p player.y     # => 5
```

Please post a simplified test code that exhibits the error, tell us the exact error message you are getting, and tell us what version of Ruby you are using.  All of this information should have been in your first post.  See http://sscce.org/ .

Comment: It looks like the culprit was somewhere else. I discovered that the example I wrote runs fine for me also. In my code, it must have been a datatype mismatch somewhere that I fixed inadvertently, because it's is working there now also. Thanks for the reply though!
P.S. Since this question has been solved/answered, is there something I should do now?

Answer (score 0):

You missed `def` in your code, `def` is the keyword for defining a method and `initialize` is the `constructor` of the class(which will be called when a new instance of the class is created).

```
#Player class containing name:string, x:integer, y:integer
class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :x, :y
  def initialize(name,x,y)
    @name = name
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end
end
```

Update:

There is no data type declaration for variables in ruby, that means you don't need to specify(declare) the datatype of variable before using it. Hence following is a valid code,

```
> var = "Robert George"
 => "Robert George" 
> var = "2010"
 => "2010"
```

Accordingly

```
> Player.new("Robert George", 10, 12)
 => #<Player:0x999b3a4 @name="Robert George", @x=10, @y=12> 
> Player.new(10, 12, "Wrong data")
 => #<Player:0x9976158 @name=10, @x=12, @y="Wrong data">
```

It works whatever datatype you pass, it is the developers responsibility to make sure that your data is valid.

Comment: Ah, oops! I just wrote that as an example, though. My actual code is correct.

However, I still have the problem that I cannot assign multiple data types. IE, name is a string, x and y are integers. It works if I set them all as one or the other, but not when I mix them, like so:

    user = User.new("Bob",4,4)

Comment: Update - It works now. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong. Perhaps I was mismatching them somewhere that I didn't notice, and inadvertently edited and fixed. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "def" before "initialize" in your example.

Comment: That was just a mistake in my example. It's correct in my actual code. My real problem is here:

    player = Player.new("Luke",5,5)

My initialization method is not happy that I am mixing strings and integers. Is there a way to do this?